# Pandas .aggregate on one dataframe, but different functions for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"area": "downtown", "type": "studio", "price": 800, "date":"2022/01/01", "is_cool_area": 1},
    {"area": "downtown", "type": "1 bedroom", "price": 1000, "date":"2022/02/01", "is_cool_area": 1},
    {"area": "downtown", "type": "1 bedroom", "price": 1000, "date":"2022/03/01", "is_cool_area": 1},
    {"area": "tomato town", "type": "1 bedroom", "price": 1000, "date":"2022/04/01", "is_cool_area": 0},
    {"area": "tomato town", "type": "2 bedroom", "price": 2000, "date":"2022/05/01", "is_cool_area": 0},
    {"area": "tomato town", "type": "shop", "price": 5000, "date":"2022/06/01", "is_cool_area": 0},
])
```

I'd like to create detailed stats for each `area` and `type`.

```
stats = {
    'price': ['mean', 'min', 'max'],
    'date': ['max'],
    'is_cool_area': ['max'], # should always be 0 or 1
}

stats = df[["area", "type", "price", "date", "is_cool_area"]].groupby(["area", "type"]).aggregate(stats)
```

This gives me the wanted result.

```
                        price                    date is_cool_area
                         mean   min   max         max          max
area        type                                                  
downtown    1 bedroom  1000.0  1000  1000  2022/03/01            1
            studio      800.0   800   800  2022/01/01            1
tomato town 1 bedroom  1000.0  1000  1000  2022/04/01            0
            2 bedroom  2000.0  2000  2000  2022/05/01            0
            shop       5000.0  5000  5000  2022/06/01            0
```

As you can see, `is_cool_area` is a boolean (always either 0 or 1) and it's always the same for a given `area`. To get the value I want, I can use `max` or `min` and it makes no difference.

Now suppose that `is_cool_area` is a string. Let's call it, "`area_description`". area_description is always the same for a given area. In the final result, I'd like a column with the `area_description`, like so:

```
                        price                    date area_description
                         mean   min   max         max          ???
area        type                                                  
downtown    1 bedroom  1000.0  1000  1000  2022/03/01            Lorem ipsum
            studio      800.0   800   800  2022/01/01            Lorem ipsum
tomato town 1 bedroom  1000.0  1000  1000  2022/04/01            Dolor sit
            2 bedroom  2000.0  2000  2000  2022/05/01            Dolor sit
            shop       5000.0  5000  5000  2022/06/01            Dolor sit
```

Suppose `area_description` is in the original `df` dataframe, just like `is_cool_area`. How would I preserve it in the final `stats` dataframe? max, min or count does not apply here, but I have to choose one of them. Is there an option to simply tell pandas the value will always be the same?

Comment: Use `'first'` or `'last'` as aggregation

Comment: How about use filter like `df.groupby(['area', 'type'])['area_description'].transform('nunique')>1`

Comment: @mozway 'first' and 'last' did the trick. Can you post as an answer?